# VC++ error, compile-time sequence operations

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I am trying to implement some functionality for compile-time integral sequences. Below is the implementation of the operation or:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

using UInt32 = std::uint32_t;

template<UInt32... s>
using Sequence = std::integer_sequence<UInt32, s...>;

template<UInt32>
constexpr bool find([[maybe_unused]] Sequence<> a = {}) noexcept {
    return false;
}

template<UInt32 x, UInt32 v, UInt32... s>
constexpr bool find([[maybe_unused]] Sequence<v, s...> a = {}) noexcept {
    if constexpr (v == x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return find<x, s...>();
    }
}

constexpr auto operator|(Sequence<>, Sequence<>) noexcept {
    return Sequence<>{};
}

template<UInt32 v, UInt32... s>
constexpr auto operator|(Sequence<v, s...>, Sequence<>) noexcept {
    return Sequence<v, s...>{};
}

template<UInt32... s, UInt32 x, UInt32... t>
constexpr auto operator|(Sequence<s...>, Sequence<x, t...>) noexcept {
    if constexpr (find<x, s...>()) {
        return Sequence<s...>{} | Sequence<t...>{};
    } else {
        return Sequence<s..., x>{} | Sequence<t...>{}; // error C2679
    }
}
```

I tried several cases to check the program by VC++ (19.16.27026.1) and many cases lead to a compiler error:

```
Error C2679 binary '|': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::integer_sequence<uint32_t,4,5>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

For example:

```
int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto a = Sequence<>{} | Sequence<>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto b = Sequence<>{} | Sequence<3, 4, 5>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto c = Sequence<1>{} | Sequence<1, 2>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto d = Sequence<1>{} | Sequence<3, 4, 5>{}; // VC++, error C2679
}
```

I tried other compilers, such as GCC 8.2.0 and Clang 7.0.0. They compile any cases without errors.

I don't understand why this error occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: You should mention that this will only compile at all with VS 2017 with ``/std:c++17`` since it uses C++17 features. That said, I still see C2679 as well even with ``/permissive-``. The poster is using the latest VS 2017 update (15.9.5 or later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand why the error occurs.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

using UInt32 = std::uint32_t;

template<UInt32... s>
using Sequence = std::integer_sequence<UInt32, s...>;

template<UInt32... s, UInt32 x, UInt32... t>
constexpr auto foo(Sequence<s...>, Sequence<x, t...>) noexcept {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto a = foo(Sequence<1, 2>{}, Sequence<3, 4, 5>{});
    [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto b = foo(Sequence<1, 2, 3>{}, Sequence<4, 5>{});
}
```

GCC 8.2.0 and Clang 7.0.0 compile successfully compile it. But VC++ (VS 2017) generates the following error:

```
Error C2664: 'int func<1,2,3,4,5>(std::integer_sequence<uint32_t,1,2>,std::integer_sequence<uint32_t,3,4,5>) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::integer_sequence<uint32_t,1,2,3>' to 'std::integer_sequence<uint32_t,1,2>'
```

As you can see from the error, the compiler tried for `b` to use an already defined function for `a`, due to the coincidence of the argument list of the function template and the templated types, which led to failure, because the final types of function parameters are different. The other two compilers defined a new function, with new types for `b`:

```
a: foo<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(Sequence<1, 2>, Sequence<3, 4, 5>)
b: foo<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(Sequence<1, 2, 3>, Sequence<4, 5>)
```

Thus, when calculating `Sequence<1>{} | Sequence<3, 4, 5>{}` the following situation occurred:

```
constexpr auto operator|<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>(Sequence<1, 2>, Sequence<3, 4, 5>) noexcept {
    if constexpr (find<3, 1, 2>()) { // false
        return Sequence<1, 2>{} | Sequence<3, 4, 5>{};
    } else {
        return Sequence<1, 2, 3>{} | Sequence<4, 5>{}; // error C2679
    }
}
```

The compiler tried to use `operator|<1, 2, 4, 5>(Sequence<1, 2>, Sequence<3, 4, 5>)`.

Now knowing the essence of the problem, I was able to rewrite the solution so that it could be compiled by all three compilers:

```
using UInt32 = std::uint32_t;

template<UInt32... s>
struct Sequence {};

template<template<UInt32...> typename S, UInt32... s>
constexpr bool empty([[maybe_unused]] S<s...> a = {}) noexcept {
    return sizeof...(s) == 0;
}

template<template<UInt32...> typename S, UInt32 x, UInt32... s>
constexpr UInt32 first([[maybe_unused]] S<x, s...> a = {}) noexcept {
    return x;
}

template<template<UInt32...> typename S>
constexpr auto tail([[maybe_unused]] S<> a = {}) noexcept {
    return S<>{};
}

template<template<UInt32...> typename S, UInt32 x, UInt32... s>
constexpr auto tail([[maybe_unused]] S<x, s...> a = {}) noexcept {
    return S<s...>{};
}

template<UInt32 x, template<UInt32...> typename S>
constexpr bool find([[maybe_unused]] S<> a = {}) noexcept {
    return false;
}

template<UInt32 x, template<UInt32...> typename S, UInt32 v, UInt32... s>
constexpr bool find([[maybe_unused]] S<v, s...> a = {}) noexcept {
    if constexpr (v == x) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return find<x>(S<s...>{});
    }
}

template<UInt32... s, typename S2>
constexpr auto operator|(Sequence<s...>, S2) noexcept {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(s) == 0) {
        return S2{};
    } else if constexpr (empty(S2{})) {
        return Sequence<s...>{};
    } else {
        constexpr auto x = first(S2{});
        if constexpr (find<x>(Sequence<s...>{})) {
            return Sequence<s...>{} | tail(S2{});
        } else {
            return Sequence<s..., x>{} | tail(S2{});
        }
    }
}
```